Can't build/open in devcontainer in VSCode/Ubuntu due to lstat failure during docker build
I ma trying to open this repo in devcontainer using VSCode running on Ubuntu, but it fails for some strange reason:
mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/java:11
[6654 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /tmp/devcontainercli-<USERNAME>/container-features/0.72.0-1734105891999/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-sample-dd36907828f3213d85a1bc1c5a049f9547307b19b12650f341b623807eb5e56e --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg VARIANT=11 --build-arg INSTALL_MAVEN=false --build-arg INSTALL_GRADLE=false --build-arg INSTALL_NODE=false --build-arg NODE_VERSION=lts/* --build-arg INSTALL_SBT=true --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /home/<USERNAME>/devcontainers/vscode-dev-containers-scala-sbt/sample/.devcontainer
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                          docker:default
ERROR: resolve : lstat /tmp/devcontainercli-<USERNAME>: no such file or directory
[7562 ms] Error: Command failed: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /tmp/devcontainercli-<USERNAME>/container-features/0.72.0-1734105891999/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-sample-dd36907828f3213d85a1bc1c5a049f9547307b19b12650f341b623807eb5e56e --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg VARIANT=11 --build-arg INSTALL_MAVEN=false --build-arg INSTALL_GRADLE=false --build-arg INSTALL_NODE=false --build-arg NODE_VERSION=lts/* --build-arg INSTALL_SBT=true --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /home/<USERNAME>/devcontainers/vscode-dev-containers-scala-sbt/sample/.devcontainer
[7562 ms]     at RtA (/home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:466:1933)
[7562 ms]     at async _m (/home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:465:1896)
[7563 ms]     at async bH (/home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:465:610)
[7563 ms]     at async TtA (/home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:3848)
[7563 ms]     at async iB (/home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:4963)
[7563 ms]     at async wrA (/home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:663:203)
[7563 ms]     at async DrA (/home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:662:14830)
[7563 ms]     at async /home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:1190
[7572 ms] Exit code 1
[7584 ms] Command failed: /usr/share/code/code /home/<USERNAME>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.394.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /home/<USERNAME>/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-41c979f9-ad0d-41be-b094-a32fe3da171d1734105883116 --workspace-folder /home/<USERNAME>/devcontainers/vscode-dev-containers-scala-sbt/sample --workspace-mount-consistency cached --gpu-availability detect --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/<USERNAME>/devcontainers/vscode-dev-containers-scala-sbt/sample --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/home/<USERNAME>/devcontainers/vscode-dev-containers-scala-sbt/sample/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/<USERNAME>/devcontainers/vscode-dev-containers-scala-sbt/sample/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration
[7585 ms] Exit code 1

It doesn't look like it is specific to a repo, since I have exactly the same issue with another devcontainer setup:
Any suggestion what might be wrong?
I use Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, Docker 27.2.0, build 3ab4256, VSCode plugin ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers Version 0.394.0
